# Table generates matrix, not column

Tags: list-manipulation

I have several columns. two of them look like the following (one for gamma, one for sigma):

```
columnA = 
  Column[{γ, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6}]
```

One of them is generated from table:

```
ColumnC =
  Column[
    Table[
      Limit[f(k, γ, σ), k -> ∞], 
      {γ, {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6}}, 
      {σ, {0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6, 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6, 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6, 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6}}]]
```

When `ColumnC` is generated, it is a 16*16 matrix, though I expected column of 16 values that are limits, which take corresponding values of `γ` and `σ`.

In the end, I want to be able to do

```
Grid[columnA, columnB, columnC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really want something like

```
gammas = {0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6};
sigmas = {0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.6};
data = 
  MapThread[{#1, #2, Limit[f[k, #1, #2], k -> ∞]} &, {gammas, sigmas}]
Grid[Prepend[data, {"γ", "σ", "Limit"}]]
```

[image: grid]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
allgammas = {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
   1.1, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6};
allsigmas = {0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6, 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6, 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 
   1.6, 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6};
allfs = Limit[f[k, #[[1]], #[[2]]], k -> \[Infinity]] & /@ 
 Transpose[{allgammas, allsigmas}]
```

This gives you a list of all the f[ ]'s evaluated at the values in the allgammas and allsigma lists. Then you can get your grid as

```
Grid[Transpose[{allgammas, allsigmas, allfs}]]
```

Of course you'll need to define f[ ] to have it do anything useful.

Comment: Thanks! I will upvote your answer as soon as I get reputation of 15.